# finding an operation for a semicircle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the following set
$$S = \{(x, y)\mid x, y \in\mathbb{R}, x^2 + y^2 = 1, y < 0\}$$
Can you think about an operation defined on the elements of $S$ such that $S$ forms a group under that operation?

Comment: Can you think of a bijection from $S$ to some set which you know has a nice group structure?

Comment: no i am unable to think of it , I am a beginner to abstract algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is a bijection from $S$ to $(-1,1)$ so then you need a bijection from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The $\tan$ function suitably scaled will work for that. Now, for two elements $s,t\in S$, just define $s\ast t = f^{-1}(f(s)+f(t))$ where $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$ is the bijection we created. Show that this operation satisfies the group axioms by using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ with addition is a group.

Comment: can u please be more specific about the function to be used

Comment: The point is that any bijection $f:S\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ will do. There are several answers already, each one using a different $f$. Of course different $f$ define different rules, but each $f$ yields a group structure.

Comment: @mathlearner I trust in your ability to scale functions so that their domain is the right size (horizontal stretching) and forming the composition of functions. We're here to help you solve the problem yourself and get an understanding, not do the whole problem for you.

Comment: You can be more geometric and use the projection from (0,0) to the line tangent to the circle at (0,-1) to construct an appropriate bijection.

Comment: Yep, or you could be more abstract and just use Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein to show such an $f$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

Given any real $a$, consider the ray $OA$ from $(0,0)$ through $(a,-1)$. It intersects $S$ at exactly one point $C(a)$, and conversely, the ray $OP$ from $(0,0)$ through a point $P$ on $S$ intersects the line $y=-1$ at exactly one point $(t(P),-1)$. So the map $C:\mathbb{R}\mapsto S$ is the inverse of the map $t:S\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. We now use the map $t$ as an isomorphism into the additive group of real numbers. Accordingly, we define *addition* of points $P,Q\in S$ as $$P+Q = C(t(P)+t(Q))$$
and (sign) inversion as
$$-P = C(-t(P))$$
and we find the neutral element as
$$N = C(0)$$
I leave it to you to work out the details of the maps $C(a)$ and $t(P)$.
Christian Blatter's construction is related; in a sense, it uses $\sinh(a)$ instead of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

A hint: The map
$$\phi:\quad {\mathbb R}\to S,\qquad u\mapsto {\bf z}=\left(\tanh u,\ -{1\over\cosh u}\right)$$
is bijective. Now transport the additive group structure on ${\mathbb R}$ to $S$. The sum ${\bf z}_1\oplus{\bf z}_2$ then appears as a complicated formula.

Comment: but what about the identity and inverse on this operation?